# How to Coerce multiple columns to factors at once for H2OFrame object?

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to follow the suggestion on question: ["Coerce multiple columns to factors at once"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180058/coerce-multiple-columns-to-factors-at-once), but it does not work for an `H2OFrame` object, for example:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:40), 4, 10, dimnames = list(1:4, LETTERS[1:10])))
data.hex <- as.h2o(data, destination_frame = "data.hex")
cols <- c("A", "C", "D", "H")
data.hex[cols] <- lapply(data.hex[cols], factor)
```

Produces the following error message:

```
Error in `[<-.H2OFrame`(`*tmp*`, cols, value = list(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  `value` can only be an H2OFrame object or a numeric or character vector
In addition: 
Warning message:
In if (is.na(value)) value <- NA_integer_ else if (!is.numeric(value) &&  :


the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

If I try to coerce as factor one by one, it works. Another workaround is to coerce as factor first the `data.frame`, then convert it into `H2OFrame` object, for example:

```
data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], factor)
data.hex <- as.h2o(data, destination_frame = "data.hex")
```

Any explanation why it happens or any better workaround?

Comment: Give it a try as `apply(data.hex[cols], 2, factor)`. I dont see `lapply` supporting `H2OFrame` objects.

Comment: @MKR it doesn't work, I get the following error: `Error in .process.stmnt(stmnt, formalz, envs) : Don't know what to do with statement: is.null x`

Comment: Yes. You are correct. All other functions like `sum`, `mean` etc works but `as.factor` gives error as `Don't know what to do with statement: is.H2OFrame ` for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do it is to use the H2OFrame `apply()` function, however, this produces the same error that @MKR mentioned.  I have created a JIRA ticket [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5420).

In theory, this should work:

```
data.hex[,cols] <- apply(X = data.hex[,cols], MARGIN = 2, FUN = as.factor)
```

For now, the workaround is:

```
for (col in cols) {
  data.hex[col] <- as.factor(data.hex[col])
}
```